# parameter passed to xacro not changing the default one

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic, xacro, universal-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to make a .xacro file for a UR5e robot, that allows choosing the gripper at launch, which means choosing different macros inside of it and I'm doing it based on the answer [here.](https://answers.ros.org/question/282902/pass-parameters-to-xacro-from-launch-file-or-otherwise/) The setup is based on the ur moveit config so launching the robot goes like this:

1. You launch `robot_setup.launch`
2. which launches `planning_execution.launch`
3. which then launches `planning_context.launch`
4. from which the robot.xacro is read as a `<param...`

I want to change a parameter at `robot_setup.launch` and have it change a parameter in the `.xacro`.

Snippet of the xacro code:

```
<xacro:arg name="gripper_type" default="other"/>
<xacro:property name="gripper_type" value="$(arg gripper_type)" />

<!-- instantiating arm and gripper -->
<xacro:if value="${gripper_type == 'robotiq'}">
    <xacro:robotiq_arg2f_140 prefix="${arm_prefix}"/>
</xacro:if>

<xacro:if value="${gripper_type == 'other'}">
    <xacro:vacuum_gripper_definition prefix="${arm_prefix}" gripper_adjustment="0.00"/>
</xacro:if>
```

So I'm trying to pass `gripper_type` from the `robot_setup.launch` all the way through the mentioned files, to change it in the `.xacro`, but in the end, the default value in the `.xacro` stays unchanged, so what am I doing wrong?

Snippet from `setup.launch`:

```
<arg name="gripper_type" default="other" />

<include file="$(find moveit_config)/launch/planning_execution.launch">
    <arg name="gripper_type" value="$(arg gripper_type)" />
</include>
```

Snippet from `planning_execution.launch`:

```
  <arg name="gripper_type"/>

  <include file="$(find moveit_config)/launch/planning_context.launch" >
    <arg name="load_robot_description" value="true"/>
    <arg name="gripper_type" value="$(arg gripper_type)"/>
  </include>
```

Snippet from `planning_context.launch`:

```
<arg name="gripper_type"/> 

<param if="$(arg load_robot_description)" name="$(arg robot_description)" command="xacro '$(find robot_config)/urdf/.xacro' gripper_type:=$(arg gripper_type)"/>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397351/parameter-passed-to-xacro-not-changing-the-default-one/) by [sniegs](https://answers.ros.org/users/70243/sniegs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2022-03-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2022-03-11**:
What command are you using to run `setup.launch`?

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-03-12**:
I deleted my answer: passing user args to xacro using a syntax like `n:=42` is supported in melodic.

**Comment by [sniegs](https://answers.ros.org/users/70243/sniegs/) on 2022-03-13**:
@tryan I run it with `roslaunch`, if it's of some importance, the roscore is on a second computer and they are connected through rosmaster, perhaps I needed to restart the whole roscore for the changes to take effect?

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2022-03-13**:
It shouldn't matter where the master is running.  I see that your xacro file defaults to "other," and that is also the default in `setup.launch`.  What command are you using that you expect to get a different value for `gripper_type`?

**Comment by [sniegs](https://answers.ros.org/users/70243/sniegs/) on 2022-03-14**:
@tryan gripper_type is the variable I've added in xacro. It has values "other" and "robotiq". I wasn't able to launch it without setting a default in both the `setup.launch` and xacro. The command for launching would be `roslaunch package setup.launch gripper_type:=robotiq` or `other`, depending on the situation

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-04-27**:\

1. Have you tried using the new syntax `<xacro:arg ...>` and `<xacro:include ...>`?
2. It's not clear to me that you can redefine an xacro:arg, or pass it "into" an included file. If xacro app reads the text content of the named file and interprets it **in the parent's context**, then the xacro:arg defined in the parent would be used to expand the content of the included file.

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-04-27**:
Ugh. I got confused between include in launch file and include in the xacro file. I will look at the issue again.

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-04-28**:
Based on what you provided above, my experiments show the `xacro:property` being set to the expected value. Do you get the desired urdf if you directly run xacro from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a very similar problem a few years ago, I asked a [question](https://answers.ros.org/question/341246/xacro-arg-not-working-in-lauch-file/) here too.

Check that you don't make the same mistake as I did. It seems like you're also using `robot_description` as a parameter. Is that parameter overwritten somewhere else to go back to the default (`gripper_type=other`)?

---

Originally posted by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) with karma: 1124 on 2022-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sniegs](https://answers.ros.org/users/70243/sniegs/) on 2022-04-29**:
Yes thank you! In the `setup.launch`, not only `planning_execution.launch` launches `.xacro` down stream, but so does `bringup.launch` so the issue was excatly that, that is set it to default in the other stream.